# setTimeout - Pass variable as time

Tags: variables, time, settimeout

I have a setTimeout, and I want to be able to use a variable as the timer:

```
var that = this;
var time = this.spawnTime;

setTimeout( function(time){ 
    that.SpawnCounter();
}, time);
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? What does `this.spawnTime` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var that = this;
var time = 1000;

setTimeout( function(time){ 
    that.SpawnCounter();
}, time);
```

The code above should work.
Maybe the problem is that `this.spawnTime` is not numeric or invaild.

Comment: Ah yeah - I was being a fool! My time was '30' ... as in 30 seconds, course, 30 seconds is 3000 as its in milliseconds :/. Cheers!

Comment: it seems u keep forgetting zeros ;p .. 30 seconds is 30000 milliseconds ;) hhh

Comment: You also can bind a scope to a method.