# Javascript Timing : is it possible and how to pass a variable to second argument of setTimeout() & setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, arguments, setinterval

I'm not able to pass an index from an array to the 2nd argument of a `window.setTimout()` function (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
function joueursCascade(){

     for (i = 0; i <= my_params.nbJoueurs; i++) {
        var del = tabDel[i]; c

        function getName(){

        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(document.getElementById('btn3').value);


        message.destinationName = document.getElementById('esp'+i).value+"/ledstate";

        mon_client.send(message);

        }       
    window.setTimeout(getName(), del);
    }
}
```

called by something like `joueursCascade()` this code should send `"my_params.nbJoueurs"` strings via MQTT at `"del"` time intervals.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here.  The second argument to the setTimeout is the duration for the timeout.

Comment: Also `getName()` is going to execute immediately due to the `()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: See also [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to make sure that your `del` variable is numerical.

Try to add `parseInt(del)`

Otherwise that question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559739/settimeout-pass-variable-as-time)

Answer (score 0):

`window.setTimeout(getName(), del);`

Should be:

`window.setTimeout(getName, del);`

If you pass `getName()` as 1st argument, then you are in fact passing the return value of that function. You need to pass in a reference to that function, hence only `getName`